# What is the difference between reply and forward in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph's [reply](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/message_reply) and [forward](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/message_forward) APIs. I am trying to understand their difference.

At first, I thought the `conversationId` might change if I use forward.

It turns out the `conversationId` won't change. So is there any difference between these two APIs? Thanks

```
POST /me/messages/{id}/reply
POST /me/messages/{id}/forward
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One replies, one forwards. These are fundamentally different operations, even if in both cases the `conversationId` is preserved. Just off the top of my head:

- Reply: the recipients on the To and CC lines are preserved, the subject is prefixed with "RE:" (or a localized equivalent), attachments are not carried over.
- Forward: No recipients are preserved, the subject is prefixed with "FW:" (or a localized equivalent), attachments are carried over.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I missed the attachment part!